# mod_rewite Rule: root/→ root/app/views/home/home.php

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, .htaccess

I am shocking at `mod_rewite`, here's the scenario:

I need a rule that rewrites `mydomain.com` to `mydomain.com/app/views/home/home.php`.

The rule, or set of rules rather, must also rewite `mydomain.com/signin` to `mydomain.com/app/views/signin/signin.php`, and work in a similar fashion for **any subdirectory**, for example: `mydomain.com/subdir` must redirect to `mydomain.com/app/views/subdir/subdir.php`.

The rules must also **work with or without the trailing slash**, for example: `….com` or `….com/`.

*Thank you all, your help is much appreciated!*

If you could outline how and why your solution works or direct me to a good resource that explains it, I'd be exceptionally grateful!

**Edit:** I have got a simple `.htaccess` file with this:

`Options +FollowSymLinks

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^$ http://mydomain.local/~Jay/some_awesome_app/app/views/home/home.php`

This does the redirect but changes the URL in the address bar too! I've not got a trailing `[R]` flag so why would this be?

Comment: Solved the **Edit**: should read `RewriteRule ^$  /~Jay/some_awesome_app/app/views/home/home.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /~Jay/awesome_app/app/views/home/home.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_]+)/?$ /~Jay/awesome_kindle_app/app/views/$1/$1.php [L]
```